# How many celery and gunicorn workers on the same server?

Tags: gunicorn, multi-core, celery

I have one server that runs a Django application served by gunicorn and a Celery task queue.

Gunicorn [docs suggest](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers) (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the default number of workers.

[Celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-c) show that the number of Celery workers defaults to 1 x $num_cores.

And both suggest experimenting to find the proper number.

My question is, what would be a good rule of thumb for running both Gunicorn and Celery on the same machine? On an eight core machine should I start with 17 Gunicorn and 8 Celery workers? Or would it make sense to start with say 9 Gunicorn and 4 Celery workers?

The system is CPU-bound, in case that helps.

Comment: Have you *tried* what happens when you use twice as many? With today's memory and cache sizes, going well beyond optimal does not hurt enough to bother finding a better rule. And if you are working at a scale where the difference might matter, you still lose more in delays in automatically scaling than you do in not maxing out each CPU.

Comment: I'm going to try it. My hope was to have an educated hypothesis before trying something that I'm not sure about.